# Estilo en un content con sass

Tags: css, sass

Tengo el siguiente codigo en sass que utilizo cuando genero un pdf con django.

```
@page {
  size: a4 portait;
  margin: 1cm;
  margin-top: 3.5cm;
  margin-bottom: 2cm;
  overflow: hidden;

  @top-center {
    height: 96px;
    width: 700px;
    content: " ";
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: -2px;
  }

  @bottom-center {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #8DCD75;
    margin: 0 3em;
    content: "Direccion: una calle"

  }
}
```

Tengo puesto que en el content del @bottom-center aparezca todo en verde, #8DCD75 , lo que me gustaria hacer es, por ejemplo, que solamente la palabra Dirección, apareciera en rojo.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder hacer eso?

Comment: Hola Danik,  puedes añadir tu codigo para poder contextualizar el problema? que has intentado ?  Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con los pseudo elementos, divide el texto en  dos partes con colores distintos:

```css
span:before {
  content: "Direccion:";
  color: #FF0000;
}

span:after {
  content: " una calle";
  color: #8DCD75;
}
```

```html
Cualquier texto <span></span>
```

Es cuestión de acomodarlo a lo que tienes.

Comment: Como tu dices: "Con la poca información que proporcionas" , espera a contestar cuando el autor edite para completar su pregunta. No deberias basarte en suposiciones para resolver algo que no está claro

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente tu posición, y lo comparto Pero en este caso, con la mínima información que hay, _un texto de color verde_ y _una de las palabras que aparece ahí sea de un color diferente_, se puede responder a lo expuesto ¿no?. En el caso de que amplíe la pregunta, si cambia el contexto, amplio la respuesta, o la elimino si lo veo conveniente. Hay preguntas con información más imprecisa o ambigua que esta. De ser distinto, no contesto.

Comment: Lo digo porque ultimamente el como  proceder en el sitio es un tema candente. Malacostumbrar a los usuarios nuevos no es bueno. Muchos cogen la respuesta, les funcionan y se van, sin aceptar la respuesta ni editar la pregunta ni  las futuras porque "ya habrá alguien que me lo resuelva".